# laravel 6: admin and super admin redirect

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to fix this problem but to no luck. I have an `Agent Model` where I want have normal agents and super agents. The normal agents can register benefactors while the super agents can register the agents and also view the normal agent's benefactors. I want to separate the two such that the normal agent cannot access the dashboard of the super agent. So i have created A super `agent middleware` as follows:

```
use Closure;
use Auth;

class Agent
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
          return $next($request);

  }
}
```

my *AgentLoginController* as follows:

```
class AgentLoginController extends Controller
{


      use AuthenticatesUsers;


      protected $redirectTo = '/benefactorDashboard';




      public function login(Request $request)
      {
          $input = $request->all();

          $this->validate($request, [
              'phoneNumber' => 'required',
              'password' => 'required',
          ]);

          if(auth()->attempt(array('phoneNumber' => $input['phoneNumber'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
          {
              if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 1) {
                  return redirect()->route('agents.dashboard');
              }else{
                  return redirect()->route('benefactors.dashboard');
              }
          }else{
              return redirect()->route('agents.signin')
                  ->with('error','Phone Number or Password Are Wrong.');
          }

      }
  }
```

I keep getting *Too may redirects * :(

is there a way I can fix this ? :)

here is my *agents* Table

```
        Schema::create('agents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('firstName');
            $table->string('secondName');
            $table->string('idNumber')->unique();
            $table->string('phoneNumber');
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('systemAdmin')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: You've got an infinite loop, because the middleware is issuing a redirect on the route it redirects to. You probably want to break this into separate middlewares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
      if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id==1)  {
          return redirect()->route('superadmin.dashboard');
      }
      elseif (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id==2) {
          return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
      }elseif (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id==3) {
          return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
      }else {
          return $next($request);
      }
    }
```